# how to make image with lazyloudin and style from css class?

Tags: html, css, class, lazy-loading

The code doesn't work, why ?and where's the mistake? Thanks in advance.
I want to do this using css and html only! ( No js ,I want use  naitve lazylouad in chrome).

```html
<img loading='lazy' class='preview' src='images/demo/spring-8fb8662b.svg'   alt=''>
```

Comment: Is the image at the correct location?

Comment: I can send the files to your gmail ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Nothing wrong with code, perhaps try to enter the full path of the image file...